# How to get an output results as text to more than one location at once?

Tags: bash, grep, ls, tree

Is there a way that I can get a resulted output to multiple locations at the same time. `ls -RsgorCh  >> /Users/User1/Text1.txt` will print the output as a text file in the given location. I want to know whether I can get the output to be printed into multiple different locations at the same time. Possible multiple locations can be

1. Terminal + Folder + Folder etc..
2. Folder + Folder + Folder etc..

Also the commands can be

```
grep
ls
tree
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tee(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html).

```
command | tee file1 file2 file3 ...
```